# Is it possible to keep in container static array?

Tags: c++

I mean not keep pointer on array

```
std::vector<int*> vector;
```

but

```
std::vector<int[]> vector;
```

The problem is to keep such array in hash_map in order to compare not pointers when Insert there but when I try like this

```
std::hash_map<std::vector<BYTE>,std::string> xxx
```

I've got an error.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question, could you please rephrase it? Also note that a `vector<int[]>` is exactly the same thing as a `vector<int*>`. Did you maybe mean a `vector<int[N]>` (where N is a compile-time constant)?

Comment: The hash map in C++ is called `unordered_map`, and this works fine for me: `std::unordered_map<std::vector<unsigned char>, std::string>`

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::array<unsigned char, N>, std::string>` is a possibility too, since the array is presumably statically-sized.

Comment: `vector<int[3]> v; v.push_back({1, 2, 3});` This even makes GCC segfault :)

Comment: even with unordered_map I've got an error `cannot convert from 'const std::vector<_Ty>' to 'size_t'`

Comment: @jrok: I don't see how that would even compile. In C++03 it's invalid syntax and in C++11 it shouldn't type check because you can't assign an initializer list (or anything else for that matter) to an array.

Comment: and if define `std::pair<BYTE[16],string> pair` then I've got an error on `pair.first=t` where `BYTE t[16]` --> `left operand must be l-value`

Comment: @Артём : That means it can't find a suitable hash function for `vector<T>`, which implies a deficiency in your compiler's standard library. [Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/libs/unordered/) comes with the correct specializations, however, so you may consider using that instead if you don't want to write the hash function yourself.

Comment: so in order to make it possible to make it works like I want I need to download BOOST library?

Comment: Not necessarily; you either need 1) a not-deficient standard library implementation, or 2) to write a hash functor for `std::vector<>` yourself, or 3) use the existing hash functor from Boost.

Comment: the problem was not in `hash_map` but in `std::pair`. It can't keep vector in it

Comment: Huh? [Of course you can](http://ideone.com/6I8hQ), why would you think otherwise..?

Comment: Yes...It is error in `table.insert(pair)`..

Comment: What type is `table`? What type is `pair`?

Answer (score 2):

You cant do `std::vector<int[]> vector`. You have to specify the size of the array for it to compile like this `std::vector<int[5]> vector`.

However, this is a bad idea because you can`t assign arrays to other arrays, etc. and you will get all kinds of errors when you try to use vector.

Instead, use `vector<vector<int>> vector` or in C++11 use `vector<std::array<int, 5>> vector`.

Also, I don't know what implementation of `hash_map` you are using so I dont know if the above solutions will work in your case. (Also, C++11 has unordered_map, so that might be preferable)

Comment: What's C++11x? I know C++0x and C++11 :)

Comment: so put my vector into another vector?

Comment: @Артём: Yes, that might work, but I don't know if the key for hash_map can be a container or not.